# How to save a property of type IFormFile in the users tables in asp.net core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Upon registering a user in asp.net core 2.0 MVC, i want to be able to upload a pdf file and save its name or Id in the table's row of that user so i can download it later. I have done everything but i am getting this error:

`The property 'ApplicationUser.contract' is of an interface type ('IFormFile'). If it is a navigation property manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type`

I do not understand what "casting it to a mapped entity type" means, am i missing something? Here is my method:

First, uploading the file:

```
   var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uploads",model.FileToUpload.GetFilename());


        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await model.FileToUpload.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
```

then, adding it to the user's property
`var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.username, Email = model.Email, contract = model.FileToUpload };`

Application user has this in the model: `public IFormFile contract {get; set;}`
and the registerviewmodel has this: `public IFormFile FileToUpload { get; set; }`

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the "mapped entity type" is from `ef core`. entity framework is getting confused as to what is supposed to be done with the property

Comment: have a look at this from the latest update: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions. This will help you do what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Your error message comes from Entity Framework. You can read in full details about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

In short, the `ApplicationUser` is assigned as an **entity** within the `DbContext` in entity framework. EF Core generally tries to map every property of an entity class to a value in the database. EF Core cannot directly map an `IFormFile` to a datatype in order to create a column in your database (you also do not need to in your case).

So, your first step would be telling EF Core "don't bother about this property". This is done by adding a `NotMapped` annotation on top of your `IFormFile` property. Next step is saving your file's name into your database for reference. I have noticed you are using the uploaded file name to do so. To avoid name conflicts, you can use something like `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` to generate a unique string (don't forget to add your extension). In order to save this file name into your database, you will need to create a string property in your `ApplicationUser` class and *save only the file name*. The file itself doesn't need to go into the `user` object.

Answer (score 0):

To add on what Neville answered, I would suggest you to create a `ApplicationUserViewModel` so you can separate front-end logic and input/validation from the model domain which you use for your DB, more specifically, in the `ApplicationUserViewModel` you acquire the file contract as `IFormFile` and in the former `ApplicationUser` class create a property Id like:

```
public class ApplicationUser : ...
{
    //... other properties
    [ForeignKey("Contracts")]
    public string ContractId { get; set; }
}
```

and create another domain model class like `Contracts` as:

```
public class Contracts
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileBlob { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
}
```

so in your actual `ApplicationUser` you don't store the whole file blob but have a reference to it, which leads to a greater performance than having to download the blob every time you instance the `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: don't think `ForeignKey` will work like this. `[ForeignKey("ContractId ")]` needs to be used for `Contracts`.

Comment: I'm using it as I described in my own project and it works as supposed. 

Comment: ok then. but according to the docs, the FK is defined in for the property